# Ensure that no console sessions are left logged in (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash

On a Linux system with `bash` as a default shell, I want to configure automatic logout with the following criteria:

- Console sessions (VGA, serial, remote KVM, etc.) are logged out after a specified period of time
- Console sessions are logged out even when running "non-idle" processes such as `top`
- SSH sessions are **not** logged out in this fashion

The intent is to ensure that no console sessions, whether over VGA or remote KVM or serial, are left logged in by accident. I want to ensure this across our site.

The `TMOUT` environment variable doesn't quite serve my needs due to the second bullet.

I could work out a quick solution that kills `login` processes of a certain age, but that seems brittle and prone to side effects. I could look for shells whose `/proc/$PID/fd/0` link to a `/dev/tty*`.

This seems like a problem that *must* have been solved already, though. Any pointers as to how this is accomplished are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this script in crontab to eliminate sessions except **ssh** every couple of minutes:

```
pkill -t $(ps  aho tty,command | egrep -v ssh | cut -d" " -f1 |sort |uniq | paste -sd",")
```

`ps  aho tty,command` would list procceses and their TTYs.
`egrep -v ssh` would remove ssh sessions from the list.
`cut -d" " -f1` would select only TTY part of ps.
`sort` & `uniq` would remove duplicates.
`paste -sd","` would make the list in comma formated to be compatible to run with `pkill` command.

> `pkill -t TTY` would kill the proccess owned by TTY

Comment: This can be saved into a bash file (killsessions.sh) and then be placed in `crontab -i` command to schedule it to run every couple of minutes or so .

Comment: I wasn't aware of pkill's `-t` command, and that was key. My oneliner was slightly different, in that it discriminated against all "tty?*" terminals: 

    for victim in /dev/tty?*; do pkill -t "$(basename $victim)"; done